# How to convert an enum variant into u8 in Rust?

Tags: rust

I would like to do that.

```
#[repr(u8)]
pub enum MessageType {
    Authentification,
    // ...
}
fn main() {
  let message_type = MessageType::Authentification;
  let binary_representation: u8 = message_type.into();
}
```

I see myself obliged to implement into by hand.

Does anyone have a solution that would use the representation to convert my type.

I think it's possible to do it in unsafe, but I'd rather not.

It could still be interesting for culture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to define the value of each variant manually, and use `as` instead of `.into()` for conversion, since `Into<u8>` is not implemented by `MessageType`:

```rust
#[repr(u8)]
pub enum MessageType {
    Authentication = 1,
    // ...
}

fn main() {
    let n = MessageType::Authentication as u8;
    println!("{}", n);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to define the values, by default in Rust enums will count up their discriminant from 0 and you can [implement `From` in terms of `as`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0462ba80f8e39e260dfd39cf64b80d31) to get the desired semantics

Comment: Oh right, and can I do it the other way round?

Comment: @cafce25 is right, you don't have to define the values manually, but keep in mind that in case you define a value one for a variant, you will need to set the value for other variants too.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "you will need to set the value for other variants too" you can also just [specify some variants](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e47db72868a0a79b8b258faa301af585) and rust will increas the discriminant for each consecutive one.